# Start ms-screenclip through explorer and get a handle or wait for exit

Tags: .net, vb.net

how can I start Windows 10's latest screen snipping tool (**"ms-screenclip:"** or shortcut Windows + Shift + S) and **either get a handle** to check or **wait until it's closed** again.

.net native

```
Process.Start("ms-screenclip:)
```

does start the application but **returns an empty process object**. I guess due to the executing application already running.

ShellExecute API does work

```
ShellExecute(Nothing, "open", "explorer.exe","ms-screenclip:", Nothing, 1)
```

but **neither returns a handle**

ShellExecuteEx also runs but I don't know how to return the handle:

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)>
Shared Function ShellExecuteEx(ByRef lpExecInfo As SHELLEXECUTEINFO) As IntPtr
End Function


<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure SHELLEXECUTEINFO
    Public cbSize As Integer
    Public fMask As UInteger
    Public hwnd As IntPtr
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>
    Public lpVerb As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>
    Public lpFile As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>
    Public lpParameters As String
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>
    Public lpDirectory As String
    Public nShow As Integer
    Public hInstApp As IntPtr
    Public lpIDList As IntPtr
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>
    Public lpClass As String
    Public hkeyClass As IntPtr
    Public dwHotKey As UInteger
    Public hIcon As IntPtr
    Public hProcess As IntPtr
End Structure
```

Am I missing something important?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same challenge at the moment. Unfortunately I have not found a really clean solution yet.

What works in my use case is to use the Win32 API:

***Obviously this is not a clean solution and should not be used in production code.***

- listen to EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND (SetWinEventHook)
- storing the window handle (you can also check the title of the active window)
- listen for EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY and check if it matches the stored handle --> window closed
- then I am checking if there is a new image in the clipboard.

I am also using a timer for a timeout check.

If I manage to solve this problem, I will let you know.

---

Edit: The final solution that works for my use case:

```
var appDataFolder = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData");
var packagesFolderPath = appDataFolder + @"\Packages\";
var taskDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(packagesFolderPath);
var packageDirs = taskDirectory.GetDirectories();
var shellExperienceDirs = packageDirs
    .Where(dir => dir.Name.StartsWith("Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_"));
foreach (var dir in shellExperienceDirs)
{
    string screenclipFolderPath = dir.FullName + @"\TempState\ScreenClip";
    if (Directory.Exists(screenclipFolderPath))
    {
        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
        {
            Path = screenclipFolderPath,
            Filter = "*.png",
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };
        watcher.Created += OnChanged; // <--- triggers my logic
        fileSystemWatchers.Add(watcher);
    }  
}
```

The app creates two images (one of it being the "thumbnail" of the popup). I'm waiting for two new images and process the larger one.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: I edited my solution to my answer. Might not really be an answer to your question though.